# Masonry.js not working when creating dynamic divs from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I'm making a page by getting links from camper news API from Free Code Camp and I'm having trouble getting `masonry.js` to work when I try to align the layout of the news links with different image sizes. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(json) {
    var html = ""
    json.forEach(function(val) {
      html += "<div class='grid-item'>";
      html += "<a href='" + val.link + "' target='_blank'>";
      if (val.image === "" || val.image === "undefined") {
        html += "<img src='" + val.author.picture + "'>";
      } else {
        html += "<img src='" + val.image + "'>";
      }
      html += "</a>"
      html += "<p><a href='" + val.link + "' target='_blank'>" + val.headline + "</a></p>"
      html += "<p>" + val.rank + " points</p>";
      html += "</div>"
    });
    $("#camper-news").html(html);
    $(".grid-item:first").removeClass().addClass("grid-sizer")
  });
  $('#camper-news').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 5
  });

});
```

I have set up a [demo](http://codepen.io/edward-hong/pen/bEjayd) in codepen containing also the html and css as well

I've tried initializing `masonry.js` with `jQuery` following the documentation provided and it's not working for some reason. I've tried debugging by setting a breakpoint where I initialized masonry in my code and clicking "step over next function call". Although I'm still new on using the Chrome debugging tool, I do see it going through masonry.pkgd.min.js file so I think I've initialized correctly masonry. I've also looked at other questions related to`masonry.js` on StackOverflow, but I haven't found the solution. I'm wondering whether it's because I've loaded the `div`s with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  initialization is in wrong position:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(json) {
    var html = ""
    json.forEach(function(val) {
      html += "<div class='grid-item'>";
      html += "<a href='" + val.link + "' target='_blank'>";
      if (val.image === "" || val.image === "undefined") {
        html += "<img src='" + val.author.picture + "'>";
      } else {
        html += "<img src='" + val.image + "'>";
      }
      html += "</a>"
      html += "<p><a href='" + val.link + "' target='_blank'>" + val.headline + "</a></p>"
      html += "<p>" + val.rank + " points</p>";
      html += "</div>"
    });
    $("#camper-news").html(html);
    $(".grid-item:first").removeClass().addClass("grid-sizer")
    $('#camper-news').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true,
      gutter: 5
    });
  });


});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGBQJK

then you have to use image loaded plugin 
to be sure that all the images have been loaded:

[Masonry images overlapping above each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697223/masonry-images-overlapping-above-each-other/17697495#17697495)

and this is the final solution:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWpZXa